# Echo Permalink in Attachment outside of loop?

Tags: attachments, permalinks

I have some code showing an image attached to a post, an image in a li list, works fine shows the image as its should.

I need the image to link through its main single post though and have tried the code below.

```
<?php
            $args = array(
               'post_type' =>  'attachment',
               'numberposts' =>  -1,
               'post_status' =>  null,
               'post_parent' =>  $post->ID
              );

              $attachments = get_posts( $args );
                 if ( $attachments ) {
                    foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
                       echo '<li>  <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="Permanent Link to<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">';
                       echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, 'full' );
                       echo '</a></li>';
                      }
                 }
?>
```

Unfortunately this doesn't print the permalink into the link. :(

Any ideas can it be done?

Thanks for looking.

Comment: could you share your solution. I am having the same issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jez, unpatient Jez :)

```
<?php
        $args = array(
           'post_type' =>  'attachment',
           'numberposts' =>  -1,
           'post_status' =>  null,
           'post_parent' =>  $post->ID
          );

          $attachments = get_posts( $args );
             if ( $attachments ) {
                foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
                   echo '<li>  <a href="'. get_permalink($attachment->ID) .'" title="Permanent Link to<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">';
                   echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, 'full' );
                   echo '</a></li>';
                  }
             }
?>
```

tried it, worked for me.

Comment: Thank you :D I need it to link to the permalink of the actual post the image is attached to though, the single.php as it were. The code above links through to the  image link...

Comment: @ungestaltbar this `title="Permanent Link to<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>` is really neat. I've been looking for a better way to title my links for awhile -- this is so simple I should have known. Thanks